# how to retrieve data from firebase data snap short

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a react native app using firebase in it. when I fetch data from firebase I got data snapshot like this

> {"674cafe2-e886-4d9d-b547-b5405d902072":{"description":"111","imageUrls":{"0":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/aam-623b6.appspot.com/o/flyers%2F674cafe2-e886-4d9d-b547-b5405d902072%2F2.jpg?alt=media&token=c56cc053-7167-44eb-9f8b-fb55664eacac","1":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/aam-623b6.appspot.com/o/flyers%2F674cafe2-e886-4d9d-b547-b5405d902072%2F1.jpg?alt=media&token=f1693b41-28db-4129-a5c7-190b96656e5b"},"latitutde":25.197669830084113,"longitude":46.33913576602936,"storename":"3023b667-3cb2-400e-8a36-1113be9e816c","title":"111","user":"8Igfk0bT06MOkzrP8Y5njOdfi0k2"}}

using snap.child.val() I was able to retrieve data from description, longitude, latitude, etc but not able to retrieve imageUrls... Because it contains child or its an array. how can I retrieve the first child from imageUrls

[image]

Comment: try using `forEach` for the `imageUrls`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't understand why you are suggesting that the question is seeking debugging help. The OP is asking how to do something, and can be fairly criticized for not providing any code to show their efforts, but there is no "debugging" involved at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code to grab the `imageUrls`:

```
  firebase.database().ref(YOUR_PATH).on('value', snap => {
        if (snap.exists()) {    
            let stringifyObject = JSON.stringify(snap)
            let obj = JSON.parse(stringifyObject);
            obj.key = snap.key
            console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.imageUrls)) // This will print your array and you do work around it
        })
```

Comment: I got Out like undefined imageUrls

Comment: print console.log(obj) and see what you get in console.

Comment: I ran this command console.log("obj.imageUrsl"+obj) and output is :- obj.imageUrsl[object Object]

Comment: its typo mistake. Check my update code and replace the imageUrls key.

Comment: But when i used console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.imageUrls) the out put was undefined

Comment: You are getting data which you need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191658/discussion-between-stv-news-kaipamangalam-and-nirmalsinh).